# Duplicate Webcam

Tags: python, webcam

I am trying to duplicate my webcam so that I can use it at the same time with two different python programs, I'm currently attempting it with v4l2loopback by using the command:

```
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback devices=2
```

and it does in fact open an extra because I get the following:

```
Dummy video device (0x0000) (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
/dev/video1

Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC (usb-0000:00:14.0-1):
/dev/video0
```

So I then try to duplicate it with the following command

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s 800x600 -i /dev/video0 -codec copy -f v4l2 /dev/video1 \ -codec copy -f v4l2 /dev/video2
```

But I get the following error:

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for ' -codec'-codec: Invalid argument
```

Is there anything I can do to fix it? or duplicate it with something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably copied that command from a website where it was displayed in two lines. The problem is the stray `\` in your command. If you remove it, it should work:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s 800x600 -i /dev/video0 -codec copy -f v4l2 /dev/video1 -codec copy -f v4l2 /dev/video2
```

---

Since `ffmpeg`'s syntax is rather complex, its documentation and many wiki pages seperate example commands to multiples lines for readability. The `\` character is used to escape the newline character in this case.

---

Probably off-topic, but if you (or anyone else) are interested in why that `\` caused problems:

In most shells, input parameters for applications are separated by the characters defined in the [IFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator) variable, which typically are *space*, *tab* and *newline* (you can put as many of those between parameters as you want). The  escape character `\` escapes the next character, which in your case was the `[space]` character and caused the input parameter to be `[space]-codec` instead of `-codec`.

ffmpeg's [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Description) is very specific about the input parameters:

> Anything found on the command line which cannot be interpreted as an option is considered to be an output url.

... and so it interpreted `[space]-codec` as an output url, which it obviously couldn't find a suitable output format for (note the space character in the error message).